# jQuery AJAX refresh page content after success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm updating my database with jQuery `.click()` and then calling my AJAX; my question is once the SQL has ran what is the best way to refresh the content on the page so I'll be able to do the previous action again, currently I'm using `window.location.reload(true);` but I don't like that method because I don't want to have the page reloading all I want is for the content on the element I used to update it with to be to match the database field after the AJAX was successful

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span[class*='star']").click(function(){
        var data = $(this).data('object');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {art_id:data.art_id,art_featured:data.art_featured},
            url: "ajax-feature.php",
            success: function(data){
                if(data == false) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                } else {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }  
            }
        });
        console.log(data.art_featured);
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<section class="row">
    <?php
    $sql_categories = "SELECT art_id, art_featured FROM app_articles" 

    if($result = query($sql_categories)){
        $list = array();

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            array_push($list, $data);
        }

        foreach($list as $i => $row){
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column one">
            <?php if($row['art_featured']==0){
            ?>
            <span data-object='{"art_id":"<?php echo $row['art_id'];?>", "art_featured":"<?php echo $row['art_featured'];?>"}' class="icon-small star"></span>
            <?php
                } else if($row['art_featured']==1) {
            ?>
            <span data-object='{"art_id":"<?php echo $row['art_id'];?>", "art_featured":"<?php echo $row['art_featured'];?>"}' class="icon-small star-color"></span>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo "FAIL";
    }
    ?>
</section>
```

EDIT:

I need to update the class `.star` or `.star-color` with `art_featured` depending on what the value of a `art_featured` is at the time, basically where ever I'm echoing out `art_featured` I need that to reload once the Ajax is successful.

EDIT:

```
$("span[class*='star']").click(function(){
    var data = $(this).data('object');
    var $this = $(this); //add this line right after the above

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {art_id:data.art_id,art_featured:data.art_featured},
        url: "ajax-feature.php",
        success:function(art_featured){
            //remember $this = $(this) from earlier? we leverage it here
            $this.data('object', $.extend($this.data('object')),{
                art_featured: art_featured
            });
        }
    });
    console.log(data.art_featured);
});
```

Comment: What is the HTML element that needs updating? Can we see it? Also can you outline what pieces of the element specifically need updating so we can better address the issues at hand?

Comment: you can use json response and replace old DOM html or value from matched json response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can just return `art_featured` after the MySQL database success, it'll send it back to the ajax success function. here, we can manipulate data, however, first we should store reference to the element that was clicked on.

```
var data = $(this).data('object');
var $this = $(this); //add this line right after the above
```

Now in our success function, instead of using `data` just use `art_featured` because that's all we are returning. Now we can update the existing data object on the target.

```
success:function(art_featured){
    //remmeber $this = $(this) from earlier? we leverage it here
    $this.data('object', $.extend($this.data('object'),{
        art_featured: art_featured
    }));
}
```

The above will extend the existing data object, allowing key:value pairs to be redefined based on the object we are extending.

You should find this working as intended.

Comment: I get the idea here, but when I implement this I have to reload the page before I can click to change my fields value like its returning 1 1 1 1 but if i reload the page it will then switch to 0 when I click it and ill have to reload the page again to switch it agian

Comment: @MitchellLayzell I'm having difficulty understanding. Nothing in the code above requires the page to reload. If you're sending back data *that was just inserted into a database* for us to use, it will be the most recent based on the code given above. If you refresh the page, you should be generating the data *from the same database we just updated* so how could it differ? *confused*

Comment: Sorry Ill try to explain, when I click my span element I run an update statement that changes my field from say 1 to 0 and vise versa once the statement is done, I want to be able to click that span element again to change the value from 0 to 1 this time, the problem is once the query runs and is done the values I used for sending data dont update until the page is reloaded so it keeps sending the same value until the page has been reloaded and loads the new value from the database

Comment: @MitchellLayzell Uh huh, And where is this `0/1` **visually** located? It has to exist somewhere, and your code doesn't shoe a 0/1 anywhere, just a `data-object` that stores information about `art_featured` / `art_id`. Neither of which will print anything to the page. Does the span have the text inside of it? Does it draw the text from the data-object somewhere that you haven't shown us?

Comment: the 0 / 1 is only located in the data-object which is what I'm using to send mySQL fields `art_featured` and `art_id` which I use to update the database, I guess those are what need to update after the sql is successful, but I'm not sure how I can really select those to change its content on success

Comment: @MitchellLayzell That is **exactly** what the code above does. Show me what the data you return from your server looks like in the `success: function(data)`. do a `console.log(data);`. What are you currently returning? As I stated above, if you are just returning `art_featured`...my code will simply extend the current `data-object ` that is **associated with the span we clicked** and will then update the `art_featured` field with `whatever we sent back from the server after updating the database`.

Comment: I've put your code in my post can you check if I'm implementing that right? but when I click say the first span it returns `1` and I click that same span again it returns `1` again but if i reload the page and click that span again it return `0` , thanks for you time and patiences

Comment: @MitchellLayzell There's an error in the code you have above...You're missing an extra `)` at the end of that `$.extend()` statement..you'll see in the console it's giving you an error..add the extra `)` at the end...or re-copy my code perhaps..dunno

Comment: @Ohmygod thanks for noticing that, I dont know how I manged that ahah, but now when I console log it 1 then my posturl and then my post url, I'm not getting a console log with it after the first click, and its not update my database anymore

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question so let's assume the content you want to change is a div with class div, and you want to replace the content with the content just sent i.e. the data. Then you would need to return the data (probably using JSON would be easiest), then your call would be

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {art_id:data.art_id,art_featured:data.art_featured},
        url: "ajax-feature.php",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
          for(n in data){
            $('.div').append('<p>'+data[n]+'</p>');
            }
        }
});
```

Note addition of dataType return as being json, then iterating over the json data by for n in data, then using n to call the data from the array. So if the third item was name then you could do something like

```
 $('.div').append('<p>Name is '+data[3]+'</p>');
```

You will have to return the data from the PHP form by json encoding it which can be done with the json_encode php function. If it's cross domain you'll have to use jsonp

EDIT:
If you already know the data you want to replace before you send the form (i.e. don't need a response) then you can just put those variables into the success call back. This will wait for the ajax to return successfully, then update your div.

So you could have this

```
var updateText = yourDataFromForm

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {art_id:data.art_id,art_featured:data.art_featured},
        url: "ajax-feature.php",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){

            $('.div').append('<p>'+updateText+'</p>');

        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would this work with data-object in HTML because I'm using that so I can use that data to work with Ajax and sending that data to mySQL statement, so how can I select something in my html data-object, thanks!

Comment: What comes before your ajax call? Is this attached to a jQuery click or submit event handler? Could you post the markup of your form. I might be able to help a little better with some further information.

Comment: Additional to my previous comment, you don't need to use the data parameter like that either, if it's in a form you can get the entire form data and use jQuery .serialize - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: I'm using click and then I'm using data-obect on a span element to get my database fields values then when I click the span I send that data through ajax with data: and then run a sql statment